# Is it possible to schedule and log automated test results on TFS, without making them part of a build/release?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-tests

If I wanted to schedule automated testing, is it possible to log the results to TFS, without making those tests part of a build or release? In other words, if I wanted to schedule daily automated tests, is it possible that the results of those tests can be logged to TFS?

This is for the local version of TFS. If this is a feature on the cloud-based version, I would consider switching to it. I couldn't find any Visual Studio extensions/packages to accomplish this, nor could I find any answers on Microsoft's support site.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked in the TFS forums? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-us/home?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: What objection do you have to doing it as part of a build or release pipeline? That's the standard way to accomplish testing and logging results.

Comment: Pedro, yes, I looked into it and wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: @DanielMann, your comment was, more or less, "Why do you not want to do it the way you said you didn't want to do it?" Should my reasoning matter? All you should be concerned with is the issue I'm trying to figure out, not my own justification for why I don't want to work with that issue that I'm clearly trying to avoid, in a certain way.

Comment: @Nastronic The reasoning matters because when something is difficult, impossible, or better achieved through different means, understanding the *why* is important in order to suggest alternatives. CI/CD pipelines are the *de facto* way for running test automation on a scheduled basis and tracking results. When a perfectly good solution to a problem exists and someone says "I know a perfectly good solution exists, but I don't want to use it", the first question I always ask is, **Why not?** It's like saying "I want to get some nails into this piece of wood, but I don't want to use a hammer."